# AD / ASP.NET / MVC: configuration error in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am doing a asp.net MVC application with vs2013. I need to do ldap authentication via active directory.

I am able to display a form, but at submit, I always get Configuration Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

    Configuration Error

    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

    Parser Error Message: An operations error occurred.

    Source Error: 

    Line 33:         <add name="ADMembershipProvider"
    Line 34:             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
    Line 35:             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Line 36:             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
    Line 37:               />
```

Here is what I have for web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://server:389/DC=us" />
</connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
            type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
            attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
              />
      </providers>
    </membership>        
  </system.web>
```

Googled quite a bit but unable to find a working solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: At the form submission, I always got error pointing to the line: <add name="ADMembershipProvider"....>. So, I looked for things related to it online. Used different attributes, etc.